# Preciso listar um campo text com valores separados por ;

Tags: php, sql-select

Tenho um campo `text` que esta sendo inserido no mesmo telefones nesse formato:

```
11 2222-3333;12 9 1111-2222;18 1111-2222;11 2222-3333
```

E preciso listar esses campos como se fosse um simples `select` em **linha** e **coluna**. o resultado que preciso é esse:

```
11 2222-3333
12 9 1111-2222
18 1111-2222
11 2222-3333
```

Answer (score 4):

Tragas os dados na sua `SQL` e coloque em uma variavel a parte dos telefones, no meu exemplo ficou na `$str` e sigo o código abaixo:

```php
<?php
   $str = '11 2222-3333;12 9 1111-2222;18 1111-2222;11 2222-3333';
   $strs = explode(';', $str);
   foreach($strs as $st){
      echo $st;
      echo PHP_EOL;
   }
```

*Exemplo:* [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/9qiqHx)

*Obs: faça as conversões no PHP, que é a melhor solução*

Answer (score 1):

Existem várias maneiras de fazer, uma opção seria fazer um **[explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php)** e em seguida **[implode()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php)**, exemplo:

```
$str = '11 2222-3333;12 9 1111-2222;18 1111-2222;11 2222-3333';
echo implode('<br/>',explode(';',$str));
```

Ou **[str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php)**

```
$str = '11 2222-3333;12 9 1111-2222;18 1111-2222;11 2222-3333';
echo str_replace(';','<br/>',$str);
```

Comment: ok em php funciona porem preciso que isso seja especificamente em um select do mysql mesmo

Comment: @user7520, o mysql não possui função nativa para quebrar string em linhas tipo `explode` do PHP, o que você pode fazer é criar uma `procedure` para contar a quantidade de separadores e pegar os valores com `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, veja um exemplo simples http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1e1e/11

Comment: @user7520 talvez isto também te ajude http://gustavostraube.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/split-string-no-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Eu usaria a str_replace:

```
$str = '11 2222-3333;12 9 1111-2222;18 1111-2222;11 2222-3333';
echo str_replace(';', '<br />', $str);
```